# does the following code in c produce a memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, null

I want to know if the following piece of code will produce a memory leak:

```
m = malloc(5);
m = NULL;
```

Comment: What definition of *memory leak* do you know/is appropriate with `malloc()`? Is there a chance `malloc(5)` returns, and something other than `NULL`?

Comment: The question gives the impression of "This is the example my teacher gave for memory leaks. Is that true?" It is hence somewhat confusing and does not make entirely clear which detail of memory leak theory you are focusing on. Could you explain which detail puzzles you? What makes you think/doubt that there might be a memory leak? Also, I agree with greybeards questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch what the problem? I'm prepaing for an exam and this is one question where I just wanted to ask for help. Is this not allowed?

Comment: Yes it is allowed, actually appreciated. But your question should be asked so that it can be answered. Consider I ask "Is there a vowel in 'A'?". How would you answer that? And if you answer "Yes." then would you have the impression that the Q/A pair makes sense and is helpful to others? Would you be really sure that you understood my core problem and have answered to the point I was so much puzzled about that I had to ask online?

Comment: Slightly more complex, if I'd ask "Is there a consonant in 'AYW`?". Then what would be your answer. Answering "Yes" might seem obvious, but there is at least one language, in which (assuming usual representation habits when discussing in English and with latin character set), the answer should actually be "No.", with a clarification of said assumptions. That is why I ask you to explain more about what puzzels you.

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote. I just try to help you getting your question out of the negative score...

Comment: Such code can produce a memory leak. But It does not have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a memory leak. The 5 allocated bytes are no longer accessible as you don't have a pointer to them.

If you save the pointer, you can still use, and free, the resources

```
unsigned char *m = malloc(5);
if (m) {
    unsigned char *p = m;
    m = NULL; // can no longer access the memory through m
    p[2] = 1; // but p is ok
    free(p);  // p is ok to free
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem! malloc failed!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: @greybeard 5 bytes aren't significant.

Comment: @machine_1 That comment was _not_ about wasting 32 bytes.

Comment: @greybeard I didn't mean that. I meant the checking for failure on allocating 5 bytes.

Comment: @machine_1 There are quite large parts of the programming world in which 5 bytes are so significant that for a statement like that you could lose your job. Once you have watched 50 people work for two months to find 10 bytes of RAM savings, you will understand.

Comment: @machine_1: it's good to get in the habit of checking the return value of (most) library functions right from the beginner's state ... otherwise it may happen that people learn is not needed